# need help writing aggregated query with grouping multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to using mongodb and mongoose for my backend stack and Im having a hard time getting from SQL to NoSQL when it comes to query building.

I have an array of object that looks like this:

```
{
 timestamp: "12313113",
 symbol: "XY",
 amount: 121212
 value: 24324234
}
```

I want to query the collection to get the following output grouped by symbol:

```
{
 symbol: xy,
 occurences: 1231
 summedAmount: 2131231
 summedValue: 23131313
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it using aggregate on the Model? My timestamp filtering works already, but the grouping throws errors

```
let result = await TransactionEvent.aggregate([
        {
            $match : {
                timestamp : { $gte: new Date(Date.now() - INTERVALS[timeframe]) }
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                what to do in here
                
                                
        }
    ]);
```

Lets say I have another field in my object with a key of "direction" that can either be "IN" our "OUT". How could I also group the occurences of these values?

Expected output

```
{
 symbol: xy,
 occurences: 1231
 summedAmount: 2131231
 summedValue: 23131313
 in: occurrences where direction property is "IN"
 out: occurences where direction property is "OUT"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$group` and `$sum`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$symbol",
      "summbedAmount": {
        "$sum": "$amount"
      },
      "summbedValue": {
        "$sum": "$value"
      },
      "occurences": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c5EuYD3sGvI)**

---

**Update 1**

you can use `$cond` to check condition.

- First parameter what is the condition
- Second parameter - what we need to do if the condition is true (We need to increase by 1 if condition true)
- Third parameter - what we need to do if the condition is false (No need to increase anything)

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$symbol",
      "summbedAmount": { "$sum": "$amount" },
      "summbedValue": { "$sum": "$value" },
      "occurences": { $sum: 1 },
      in: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$direction", "in" ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      },
      out: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$direction", "out" ] }, 1, 0 ] }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MrpGslelieK)**

Comment: Thank you mate. It is working as I wanted. I got a little tripped on the _id : $symbol field that was throwing me errors. I need to get used to the query language of mongodb. Ty

Comment: can you explain what the 1 is reffering to in the $sum ?

Comment: You are welcome to the mongo world and stackoverflow.

Comment: also if I had another property like direction that can be either "IN" or "OUT". How could I group that and sum up transactions wherre value = IN and where value = OUT?

Comment: @headliner090 when we group, we say if there any occurrence exists the same we use to group (`$symbol`), increase the count one by one,. SO you get to know how many object were there

Comment: @headliner090 can you open another question or update this question if its relevant and let me know!! I want to know what is the output you expect...

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB's `$group` stage, the `_id` key is mandatory and
it should be the keys which you want to be merged (It's `symbol` in your case).
Make sure that you pre-fix it with a `$ sign since you are referencing a key in your document.

Following the `_id` key, you can add all the additional operations to be performed for the required keys. In your specific use case, use `$sum` to add values to the user-defined key.

> Note: Use `"$sum": 1` to add 1 for each occurences ans `"$sum": "$<Key-Name>"` to add existing key's value.

Below code should be your `$group` stage

```
{
     "$group": {
          "_id": "$symbol",  // Group by key (Use Sub-Object to group by multiple keys
          "occurences": {"$sum": 1},  // Add `1` for each occurences
          "summedAmount": {"$sum": "$amount"},  // Add `amount` values of grouped data
          "summedValue": {"$sum": "$value"},  // Add `value` values of grouped data
     }
}
```

Comment if you have any additional doubts.